# How to use Sublime Text as a Multimarkdown editor?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Is it possible to use Sublime Text 2 as a Multimarkdown editor with preview in browser as I do with Markdown? Thank you. Hugo

Answer (score 3):

[Sublime Markdown Preview](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview) should do it ;)

Comment: This is also available in [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation) for easy installation.

Answer (score 1):

[MarkdownEditing](http://ttscoff.github.com/MarkdownEditing/) is good.

> Better Markdown Editing features for Sublime Text 2
>
> This package will make MarkdownEditor your default theme for Markdown/MultiMarkdown files. Adjust it to your liking or remove the line from the .sublime-settings files

Comment: When recommending software, please follow [these guidelines](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225).